# ValueError: X has 2 features, but MinMaxScaler is expecting 1 features as input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, scikit-learn

I have numpy arrays split into X and y, originally made from Pandas DataFrame as follows:

```
>> X
array([[ 2.86556780e-03,  1.87100798e-01],
   [ 2.56781670e-04,  2.45417491e-01],
   [ 2.35497137e-03,  1.76615342e-01],
   ...,
   [ 2.30078468e-03, -4.16726811e-60],
   [ 5.66213972e-03, -2.98597808e-60],
   [ 4.39503905e-03, -2.13954678e-60]])

>> y
array([19.08666992, 19.09239006, 19.08938026, ..., 45.21157634,
   45.19350761, 45.13230675])
```

I split them into training and test dataset as follows:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
```

Before scaling the data, I reshape my labels as follows:

```
y_train= y_train.reshape((-1,1))
y_test= y_test.reshape((-1,1))
```

Using sklearn `MinMaxScaler` I then `fit_transform` my training_data as follows:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
y_train = scaler.fit_transform(y_train)
```

I then try to `transform` my test data using `MinMaxScaler` as follows:

```
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
y_test = scaler.transform(y_test)
```

But test dataset is not transformed as I get the following error:

```
----> 1 X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

ValueError: X has 2 features, but MinMaxScaler is expecting 1 features as input.
```

Can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `scaler` is fit to `y_train` which has a single feature, whereas `X_test` has 2 features.

You have to define different scaler objects for `X` and `y`:

```
scaler_X = MinMaxScaler()
scaler_Y = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler_X.fit_transform(X_train)
y_train = scaler_Y.fit_transform(y_train)
X_test = scaler_X.transform(X_test)
y_test = scaler_Y.transform(y_test)
```

another way to do the same job is to use a scaler fit to `X_train` to transform `X_test`; then use a scaler fit to `y_train` to transform `y_test`:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
y_train = scaler.fit_transform(y_train)
y_test = scaler.transform(y_test)
```