# How do I fix this ValueError on my linear regression python script

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

```
X_train = np.array([[crashPoint(0), crashPoint(1), crashPoint(2)], [crashPoint(1), crashPoint(2), crashPoint(3)], [crashPoint(2), crashPoint(3), crashPoint(4)], [crashPoint(3), crashPoint(4), crashPoint(5)], [crashPoint(4), crashPoint(5), crashPoint(6)], [crashPoint(5), crashPoint(6), crashPoint(7)], [crashPoint(6), crashPoint(7), crashPoint(8)]])
y_train = np.array([crashPoint(3), crashPoint(4), crashPoint(5), crashPoint(6), crashPoint(7), crashPoint(8), crashPoint(9)])

# Scale the input values
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
y_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(y_train.reshape(-1, 1))

# Create a Linear Regression model
model = LinearRegression()

# Train the model using the training data
model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train_scaled)

# Use the model to predict the next crashPoint value
next_crashpoint_scaled = model.predict(scaler.transform([[crashPoint(7), crashPoint(8), crashPoint(9)]]))

# Inverse transform the predicted value to get the actual crashPoint
next_crashpoint = scaler.inverse_transform(next_crashpoint_scaled)

# Print the predicted crashPoint value
print(f"The predicted crashPoint value is: {int(next_crashpoint[0][0])}")
```

This is the script that im working on, when I run it the console prints this error
`ValueError: X has 3 features, but MinMaxScaler is expecting 1 features as input.`
can anybody help me find a fix for this?

I was expecting the script to print out the predicted crashpoint

Comment: This might help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71386142/valueerror-x-has-2-features-but-minmaxscaler-is-expecting-1-features-as-input

Comment: Its happening because when you call fit_transform second time the scaler is fitted on single feature column since y_train shape in (None,1). Therefore when you provide multiple crashpoints to scaler it gives the error.